# How to deal with C structs with runtime determined layouts?

Tags: c

In my code, I need to deal with one of two structs that share almost all of the members, but their offsets can only be determined at runtime.
Something like:

```
struct type1 {int a, char b[8], int c};
struct type2 {int a, char b[16], int c};
```

There's nothing I can do about the layout of these structs, because it's dictated by hardware.

So every time I want to access a member I would need to do something like:

```
void foo(void *data)
{
     if (is_type1)
         ((struct type1 *)(data))->c = 5;
     else
         ((struct type2 *)(data))->c = 5;
}
```

And that is not very elegant.

I was wondering if there is some recipe for a more elegant handling of this situation, besides hiding all this ugliness in macros, which is the solution I will resort to in absence of a better one.

Thanks.

Comment: This code looks good. Why do you think that this approach of yours is not very elegant?

Comment: It becomes a lot less elegant if he has to add a `type3` :)

Comment: Makes you wish for polymorphism...

Comment: What do you want? ... maybe, assigning memory alignment is one way to solve your problem?

Comment: these two structures end up the same on many architectures :)

Comment: @unkulunkulu, yes my choice of numbers doesn't illustrate the problem.Thanks.Edited...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the order, I would join them into the same struct as a union:

```
struct type12 { union { struct type1 type1; struct type2 type2; } types; int type; };

void foo(struct type12 *data)
{
    if (data->type == 1)
         data->types.type1.c = 5
    else
         data->types.type2.c = 5;
}
```

Perhaps not a big improvement, but you can avoid the type casts...

Comment: In practice though, the `type` field should always be first.

Comment: I had it first, at first. Then placed it last so that it still maps a void * onto the type1/type2 data...

Answer (score 0):

Move the shared members into a seperate struct, and use that as the first member of the two types. This has the advantage that you don't have to test types (or even care about them) in order to read/write the shared data.

```
#include <stdio.h>      
struct shared_data {
  int a;
  int c;
};
struct type1 {
  struct shared_data shared;
  char b[2];
};
struct type2 {
  struct shared_data shared;
  char b[4];
};

void foo(void *data)
{
     ((struct shared_data*)(data))->c = 5;
}    

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct type1 a;
    struct type2 b;

    foo(&a);
    foo(&b);

    printf("A: %d\nB: %d\n", a.shared.c, b.shared.c);
}
```

Outputs

```
A: 5
B: 5
```

Comment: I'm guessing that since it's based on hardware, the order of the members in the struct matter.

Comment: The order of the members in the `struct shared_data` doesn't matter. The `struct shared_data` is first in all the types using it. You don't have to have it first, you can use `offsetof` to find it, but then you have to switch based on type again.

Comment: I'm saying that on the specific hardware he's using ("nothing I can do about the layout of these structs, because it's dictated by hardware"), those structs might map to memory layouts of the hardware (think embedded systems).